# Running sencha app watch on MacOS Sierra fails with the error- 'PhantomJS sass build exited with code : 139'

Tags: extjs, phantomjs, macos-sierra, extjs6, sencha-cmd

When I run Sencha app watch (sencha app watch), my build fails with the following error:

BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: PhantomJS sass build exited with code : 139
[ERR]   at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)

This started happening right after an upgrade to MacOS Sierra.

My Sencha CMD version is 6.1.3.42

ExtJS version 6.0.2

After reading a lot of posts, I have come to the conclusion that Sierra requires a 2.x version of phantomJS while this specific version of Sencha requires PhantomJS version of 1.9.8.

Is there no workaround apart from a Sencha CMD upgrade for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sencha Cmd uses the version of PhantomJS that comes bundled with it. For Sencha Cmd 6.1.3.42, that's 2.1.1.

You can test that yourself - `<Sencha CMD location>/bin/osx/phantomjs/phantomjs --version`

Earlier versions of Sencha Cmd (e.g. 6.0.1.76) used PhantomJS 1.9.x, which doesn't work under Sierra. It's possible you're still configured to use one of those.